# If we let $T : R^2 \to R^2$ be a linear transformation. Consider two bases $B$ and $D$ of the vector space $R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Having trouble with this problem and not only looking for a answer but some explanation of what is going on in the problem. If we let $T : R^2 \to R^2$ be a linear transformation. Consdider two bases $B$ and $D$ of the vector space $R^2$, where $B=\{v_1,v_2\}$ with $ v_1 = 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
-2
\\1  
\end{bmatrix}\right)$ and  $ v_2 = 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1
\\1  
\end{bmatrix}\right)$ and where $D = \{w_1,w_2\}$ with  $ w_1 = 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
-1
\\4  
\end{bmatrix}\right)$ and  $ w_2 = 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
0
\\1  
\end{bmatrix}\right)$. Suppose that  $ A = 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1&2  
\\-1 &4   
\end{bmatrix}\right) = M_{D_<-D(T)}$. I need to find the matrix $B = M_{B<-B}(T)$

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question. Do you need the representation of $T$ in the the $D$ basis?

Comment: @caverac I need to find the matrix $B = M_{B<-B}(T)$

Comment: @AOrtiz thank you for the edit, any idea how to work through this problem

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to write matricez that change coordinates between the basis $B$ and $D$. There is no standard notation for this. Let's use this one: $M_{B\leftarrow D}$ is the matriz that converts the coordinates given in the base $D$ to the base $B$ (more on how to build it soon). If $[T]_D$ and $[T]_B$ are the matrices of $T$ in respect to the bases $D$ and $B$ respectively we have $$[T]_B = M_{B\leftarrow D} [T]_D M_{D\leftarrow B} = M_{B\leftarrow D} [T]_D (M_{B\leftarrow D})^{-1}.$$

To build $M_{B\leftarrow D}$ you must write both $w_1$ and $w_2$ as linear combinations of $v_1$ and $v_2$ and store the coefficients in the first and second columns of $M_{B\leftarrow D}$.

More concretely: $w_1 = \frac{5}{3}v_1+\frac{7}{3}v_2$ and $w_2=\frac{1}{3}v_1+\frac{2}{3}v_2$. Hence. $$M_{B\leftarrow D}=\left[\begin{array}{cc} 
\frac{5}{3}&\frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{7}{3}&\frac{2}{3}
\end{array}\right].$$

Straight forward computations gives you what you need.

Comment: thanks for your answer,  I am looking to go $B = M_{B<-B}(T)$ so is that the same thing you have provided? doesn't yours go from $B<-D$